# Is there a way to update Docker "Resources" settings from the command line on an EC2 instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to increase the memory allocation of a specific container I'm running on an EC2 instance. I was able to do this **locally** by adding the `mem_limit: 4GB` into my docker-compose file (using version 2 not 3) and this did not work until I changed my settings in Docker desktop to be greater than the memory limit I was specifying:

[image: Image showing Docker Desktop settings on the resource tab which has a slider to change the maximum resource for CPU, Memory, Swap, and Disk image size]

My question is as follows, is it possible to change this memory slider setting from the command line and therefore would it be possible to do it on an EC2 instance and without docker desktop? I've been through the docs but was unable to find anything specific to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Docker Desktop setting, which is only necessary because of the way docker containers run in a VM on Windows and Mac computers. On an EC2 Linux server there is no limit like that, docker processes can use as much resources as the server has available.

Comment: Thanks Mark - checked this and realised it was indeed the case!